# Given initial conditions, find the maximum height reached by an object thrown upwards and its velocity on returning to the ground

Tags: calculus

A ball is thrown straight upward from the ground with initial velocity $v_0=+96$ ft/s. It's height (in feet) at time $t$ seconds is given by $y(t) = -16t^2 + 96t$

1. Find the maximum height of the ball
2. Find the velocity with which the ball hits the ground upon its return.

Comment: You'll need to edit your post to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

1. For maximum height, equate $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ and find the
   corresponding value of $t=t'$(say) and calculate $y(t')$.
2. Solve for $y(t)=0$ and one of the values of $t$ will be $0$. The
   other value of $t=t_1$ will be the time when the ball hits the
   ground. Required velocity is $\frac{dy}{dt}$ at $t=t_1$.